# How to use JavaScript's setattribute to affect multiple elements?

Tags: javascript, setattribute

I have many div with the class `publish_0` that I would like to change to `publish_1` on click of a button.

Right now I use this but it only change one item.

How to I apply the setattribute to all item that have the `publish_0`.

```
document.querySelector('.publish_0').setAttribute("class", "publish_1");
```

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You can use this with jquery:

```
$(".publish_0").attr("class", "publish_1")
```

Alternatively, use getElementsByClassName and loop through the DOM elements returned.

Comment: Vivek, while I appreciate your suggestion of using jQuery, the OP has expressed their question with respect to Vanilla JavaScript. Please consider this for future answers.

Answer (score 44):

You need to use a loop to iterate over all the elements and set their class attribute value individually:

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll('.publish_0');
for (var i=0; i < els.length; i++) {
    els[i].setAttribute("class", "publish_1");
}
```

Comment: As you are using a class you can use `getElementsByClassname` instead of `querySelectorAll`, it's performing way better. See an example [here](https://jsperf.com/getelementsbyclassname-vs-queryselectorall/2)

Answer (score 14):

For when you can't use jQuery but want the convenience of something similar, you can do the following.  Add the following code to the top of the file or somewhere else easily visible.

```
NodeList.prototype.forEach = NodeList.prototype.forEach || Array.prototype.forEach;
```

Now in your code you can do this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('body,main,article,[class*=content],[class*=center]')
        .forEach((function(x){ x.setAttribute("style","width:1920px");}))
```

Or even nicer yet, if the browser supports ECMAScript2015 you can use arrow syntax:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[class*=content]')
        .forEach( x=> x.setAttribute("style","width:1200px"))
```

You can put the statement all on one line if you'd like.

Comment: No need for the `forEach` fix [any more](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_nodelist_foreach) (since 2017-10-17)

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. My choice

I use Vanilla JS [**for…of loops**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of).

#### 2. Advantages

1. In my opinion, this is a more intuitive syntax than the syntax in [**@Asad Saeeduddin’s**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18455368/5951529) and [**@Derek Ziemba’s**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35232956/5951529) answers.
2. [**Unicorn**](https://github.com/sindresorhus/eslint-plugin-unicorn) code style checker prefers `for…of` to `forEach()` method. [**`no-array-for-each` Unicorn’s rule**](https://github.com/sindresorhus/eslint-plugin-unicorn/blob/main/docs/rules/no-array-for-each.md):

   > Benefits of `for…of` statement over the `forEach` method can include:
   >
   > 1. Faster
   > 2. Better readability
   > 3. Ability to exit early with `break` or `return`
   >
   > Additionally, using `for…of` has great benefits if you are using TypeScript, because it does not cause a function boundary to be crossed. This means that type-narrowing earlier on in the current scope will work properly while inside of the loop (without having to re-type-narrow). Furthermore, any mutated variables inside of the loop will picked up on for the purposes of determining if a variable is being used.

#### 3. MCVE

[**Live demonstration on LiveCodes**](https://v24.livecodes.io/?x=id/j4tm6ypg5vb):

```html
<button>Change the class for multiple elements!</button>

<div class="publish_0">Kira Amazing!</div>

<div class="publish_0">Kira Goddess!</div>

<div class="publish_0">Kira Incredible!</div>
```

```
$KiraMarginBottom
    margin-bottom 1rem

button
    @extend $KiraMarginBottom

.publish_0
    background-color yellow
    @extend $KiraMarginBottom

.publish_1
    background-color pink
    @extend $KiraMarginBottom
```

```coffee
kiraButton = document.querySelector("button")

kiraChangeClassByClickForMultipleElements = ->

    kiraElementsNeedingClassChanges = document.querySelectorAll(".publish_0")

    for kiraElementInNeedOfClassChange from kiraElementsNeedingClassChanges

        ###
        [INFO] Or use “classList” or “className” properties:
        https://stackoverflow.com/a/196038/5951529
        https://stackoverflow.com/a/196016/5951529

        [INFO] “setAttribute()” method also works. I left it to make it clearer how to add attributes:
        https://stackoverflow.com/a/8428872/5951529
        ###
        kiraElementInNeedOfClassChange.setAttribute "class", "publish_1"

        console.log(kiraElementInNeedOfClassChange.className)

kiraButton.addEventListener "click", kiraChangeClassByClickForMultipleElements
```

[image: .publish_0 class]

The code above changes the class `.publish_0` to `.publish_1` for all elements with the class `.publish_0` after clicking or pressing the `Change the class for multiple elements!` button:

[image: .publish_1 class]

#### 4. Browser compatibility

[**`for…of` statement on caniuse.com**](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_statements_for_of):

[image: for…of on CanIUse]

Safari supports `for…of` since 2013, Chrome and Opera since 2014, Edge since 2015 and Firefox since 2017.

#### 5. Relevance of the answer

This answer is relevant as of February 2024. In the future, data of my answer may be obsolete.