# .attr('checked', 'checked') / .attr('checked', 'true') not adding attribute in html

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-1.4

This is my JavaScript, using jQuery:

```
$("#E_DIV_H input[value='E,F']").attr('checked', 'checked');
var data = $('#E_DIV_H').html();
$('#copy').html(data);
```

When it copies the data from one `<div>` (`#E_DIV_H`) to another DIV (`#copy`), it unchecks the check box, which should already be checked due to the following code!

```
$("#E_DIV_H input[value='E,F']").attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Using Firebug, I see that `.attr('checked', 'checked')` is checking the check box without adding the attribute.

Is there any solution that works cross-browser? I’m using jQuery 1.4.2.

Comment: Search for "attributes vs properties".

Comment: @Vohuman But `.attr()` should update the DOM node attribute and `.prop()` was added in 1.6

Comment: @Vohuman prop work for jQuery 1.6+ version!!

Comment: @ShahidGhafoor http://jsbin.com/givizu/1/edit?html,js,console it seems like this works just fine. Press 'Run' on the box, it says `"<input id=\"myCheckbox\" type=\"checkbox\" checked=\"checked\">"`, so the box does seem to have an attribute set now. Could you link a demo of where it doesn't work?

Comment: Did I write `prop` method?

Comment: The question is how do you check updated HTML???

Comment: @Vohuman No but was just wondering: doesn't `attr()` in jq1.4.2 update attribute then?

Comment: @Vohuman I just checked, it doesn't in fact  http://jsfiddle.net/a23eebzr/

Comment: @A.Wolff Yes, older `attr` tries to modify the properties if it can.

Comment: @A.Wolff I checked the updated HTML using FireBug! in firefox

Comment: @Vohuman Ya, just checked the `.attr()` DOC, it is cleary explains there. Good to remember!

Comment: @ShahidGhafoor you'd have to use javascript `setAttribute('checked', true)` method instead

Comment: @A.Wolff can u please gave me an example , because `$("#E_DIV_H input[value='E,F']").setAttribute('checked', true);` not working

Comment: @Joeytje50 it work on jsfiddle also http://jsfiddle.net/9wq20y45/ but not working on any browser ! :( see above link and if you make html on local , its not working :(

Comment: @ShahidGhafoor that link does work fine for me though. What browser are you using?

Comment: @ShahidGhafoor You have to call it on DOM element, not jQuery object. If you only target one element, then you can use: `$("#E_DIV_H input[value='E,F']")[0].setAttribute('checked', true);`  For more than one element, you'll need to iterate through returned collection, e.g: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18455368/1414562

Comment: @A.Wolff yes! its working now !! thanks! please put your answer ! I'll accept ;)

Comment: @Joeytje50 if you make html file on local machine! and if u run it , it will not work, any browser firefox, chrome and IE ! but `setAttribute` solved my problem! thanks u also for cooperate !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update boolean attribute as `checked` in jQuery version <1.6, you should use javascript `setAttribute()` method, e.g:

```
$("#E_DIV_H input[value='E,F']")[0].setAttribute('checked', true);
```

If you have more than one element to target, then you have to iterate through collection, e.g:

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll("#E_DIV_H input[value='E,F']");
for (var i=0; i < els.length; i++) {
    els[i].setAttribute("checked", true);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to copy an element, use [`.clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone). Working with HTML is messy.

```
$('#copy').replaceWith(
    $('#E_DIV_H').clone().attr('id', 'copy')
);
```

Anyways, the reason it isn’t working is probably because (as you know) `.prop()` was introduced in 1.6.0; before then, `.attr()` did its job and is probably setting the property instead of the attribute.