# setAttribute("checked", "checked") only works one time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am facing one issue

**HTML**

```
<input id="cb" type="checkbox" name="Employment_Staus" value="E" />
<input type="button" value="Check" id="id" />
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('#id').click(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]')[0].setAttribute("checked", "checked");
});
```

First time when I click on `check button`, it works!(it check the check-box ), then I manually uncheck the check box!

When I press `check button` again after uncheck manually , it not work!

I don't want to use attr or prop etc etc !!

**Example**

http://jsfiddle.net/wL6qr0hp/4/

Comment: `$('input[type="checkbox"]')[0].checked = true` or `$('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", true);`

Comment: Why are you using jQuery and then trying to avoid half of its features?

Comment: [Here's a fixed version of your jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/atw3maj4/)

Comment: @tymeJV sorry! `$('input[type="checkbox"]')[0].checked = true` its not adding checked = true attribute in dom!!

Comment: @Pointy I don't want to use attr or prop etc etc !! ! I want to see this attribute with element when it checked !! prop / attr not do that [Check this] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27679690/attrchecked-checked-attrchecked-true-not-adding-attribute-in-h)

Comment: @Quentin when I use prop/ attribute ! I check that check-box, when I see this element using firebug, it not add checked=true attribute in that element! hope u understand !!

Comment: @ShahidGhafoor — That's because Firebug shows the attribute. As I said in my answer, the attribute and the property represent different things.

Comment: I want when check-box checked ! this statement `<input id="cb" type="checkbox" name="Employment_Staus" value="E" />` should become this `<input id="cb" type="checkbox" name="Employment_Staus" value="E" checked=true />`

Comment: Your comments don't make any sense. The updated fiddle shows that the button works properly; what difference does Firebug make?

Comment: @Quentin the first statement is without checked= true attribute `<input id="cb" type="checkbox" name="Employment_Staus" value="E" />` and this statement has checked=true attribute in element `<input id="cb" type="checkbox" name="Employment_Staus" value="E" checked=true />` this is the difference! one has checked=true attribute and other one has not!! so, I NEED, WHEN THIS CHECK BOX CHECKED , THEN checked=true must be in this element like `checked=true` complete it should seems following `<input id="cb" type="checkbox" name="Employment_Staus" value="E" checked=true />` hope u got!!

Comment: Then you have to set both, the property and the attribute, and you have to update the attribute whenever the state changes.

Comment: @Quentin for more detail!! why jsfiddle not showing cheched=true attribute when check-box is checked !! I required that !!!

Comment: @ShahidGhafoor — See the first line of my answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `checked` **attribute** sets the *default* state, not the *current* state.

Modify the `checked` **property** (with `.checked = true`) instead.

Comment: I don't want to use attr or prop etc etc !!

Comment: @ShahidGhafoor - Why not?

Comment: @ShahidGhafoor The code in Quentin's answer doesn't. I can't think of a good reason to include jQuery, but not make use of its features.

Comment: @j08691 [This is the reason](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27679690/attrchecked-checked-attrchecked-true-not-adding-attribute-in-h) , they not set checked=true attribute!! but setAttribute do that !!

Comment: I want when check-box checked ! this statement `<input id="cb" type="checkbox" name="Employment_Staus" value="E" />` should become this `<input id="cb" type="checkbox" name="Employment_Staus" value="E" checked=true />`