# jQuery slider converted to vanilla JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm building a slider and I want to avoid jQuery.
So I'm trying to convert some jQuery code to vanilla JavaScript.

Here's the jQuery:

```
setInterval(function() {
  var $curr = $('#slider1 input[type=radio]:checked');  
  var $next = $curr.next('input');
  if(!$next.length) $next = $('#slider1 input[type=radio]').first();
  $next.prop('checked', true);

}, 2000);
```

My code is below, but it's not working.
What's going wrong?

```js
setInterval(() => {
  let $curr = document.querySelectorAll('#slider1 input[type=radio]:checked'),
    $next = $curr.nextSibling;

  if (!$next.length) {
    $next = document.querySelectorAll('#slider1 input[type=radio]').firstChild;
  }
  $next.setAttribute('checked', true);
}, 3000);
```

```css
.csslider {
  -moz-perspective: 1300px;
  -ms-perspective: 1300px;
  -webkit-perspective: 1300px;
  perspective: 1300px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 22px;
}

.csslider>input {
  display: none;
}

.csslider>input:nth-of-type(10):checked~ul li:first-of-type {
  margin-left: -900%;
}

.csslider>input:nth-of-type(9):checked~ul li:first-of-type {
  margin-left: -800%;
}

.csslider>input:nth-of-type(8):checked~ul li:first-of-type {
  margin-left: -700%;
}

.csslider>input:nth-of-type(7):checked~ul li:first-of-type {
  margin-left: -600%;
}

.csslider>input:nth-of-type(6):checked~ul li:first-of-type {
  margin-left: -500%;
}

.csslider>input:nth-of-type(5):checked~ul li:first-of-type {
  margin-left: -400%;
}

.csslider>input:nth-of-type(4):checked~ul li:first-of-type {
  margin-left: -300%;
}

.csslider>input:nth-of-type(3):checked~ul li:first-of-type {
  margin-left: -200%;
}

.csslider>input:nth-of-type(2):checked~ul li:first-of-type {
  margin-left: -100%;
}

.csslider>input:nth-of-type(1):checked~ul li:first-of-type {
  margin-left: 0%;
}

.csslider>ul {
  position: relative;
  width: 820px;
  height: 420px;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  background-color: #3A3A3A;
  border: 10px solid #3A3A3A;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.csslider>ul>li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-size: initial;
  line-height: normal;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 1.3, 0.65, 1);
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 1.3, 0.65, 1);
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 1.3, 0.65, 1);
  vertical-align: top;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  white-space: normal;
}

.csslider>ul>li.scrollable {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.csslider>.navigation {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -8px;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.csslider>.navigation>div {
  margin-left: -100%;
}

.csslider>.navigation label {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 4px;
  padding: 4px;
  background: #3A3A3A;
}

.csslider>.navigation label:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.csslider>.navigation label:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -6px;
  margin-top: -6px;
  background: #71ad37;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 6px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.csslider>.arrows {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.csslider.inside .navigation {
  bottom: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.csslider.inside .navigation label {
  border: 1px solid #7e7e7e;
}

.csslider>input:nth-of-type(1):checked~.navigation label:nth-of-type(1):after,
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(2):checked~.navigation label:nth-of-type(2):after,
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(3):checked~.navigation label:nth-of-type(3):after,
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(4):checked~.navigation label:nth-of-type(4):after,
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(5):checked~.navigation label:nth-of-type(5):after,
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(6):checked~.navigation label:nth-of-type(6):after,
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(7):checked~.navigation label:nth-of-type(7):after,
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(8):checked~.navigation label:nth-of-type(8):after,
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(9):checked~.navigation label:nth-of-type(9):after,
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(10):checked~.navigation label:nth-of-type(10):after,
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(11):checked~.navigation label:nth-of-type(11):after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.csslider>.arrows {
  position: absolute;
  left: -31px;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 26px;
  padding: 0 31px;
  z-index: 0;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.csslider>.arrows label {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: -50%;
  padding: 13px;
  box-shadow: inset 2px -2px 0 1px #3A3A3A;
  cursor: pointer;
  -moz-transition: box-shadow 0.15s, margin 0.15s;
  -o-transition: box-shadow 0.15s, margin 0.15s;
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow 0.15s, margin 0.15s;
  transition: box-shadow 0.15s, margin 0.15s;
}

.csslider>.arrows label:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 3px -3px 0 2px #71ad37;
  margin: 0 0px;
}

.csslider>.arrows label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -100%;
  left: -100%;
  height: 300%;
  width: 300%;
}

.csslider.infinity>input:first-of-type:checked~.arrows label.goto-last,
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(1):checked~.arrows>label:nth-of-type(0),
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(2):checked~.arrows>label:nth-of-type(1),
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(3):checked~.arrows>label:nth-of-type(2),
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(4):checked~.arrows>label:nth-of-type(3),
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(5):checked~.arrows>label:nth-of-type(4),
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(6):checked~.arrows>label:nth-of-type(5),
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(7):checked~.arrows>label:nth-of-type(6),
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(8):checked~.arrows>label:nth-of-type(7),
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(9):checked~.arrows>label:nth-of-type(8),
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(10):checked~.arrows>label:nth-of-type(9),
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(11):checked~.arrows>label:nth-of-type(10) {
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  right: auto;
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.csslider.infinity>input:last-of-type:checked~.arrows label.goto-first,
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(1):checked~.arrows>label:nth-of-type(2),
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(2):checked~.arrows>label:nth-of-type(3),
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(3):checked~.arrows>label:nth-of-type(4),
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(4):checked~.arrows>label:nth-of-type(5),
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(5):checked~.arrows>label:nth-of-type(6),
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(6):checked~.arrows>label:nth-of-type(7),
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(7):checked~.arrows>label:nth-of-type(8),
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(8):checked~.arrows>label:nth-of-type(9),
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(9):checked~.arrows>label:nth-of-type(10),
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(10):checked~.arrows>label:nth-of-type(11),
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(11):checked~.arrows>label:nth-of-type(12) {
  display: block;
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
  -moz-transform: rotate(225deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(225deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(225deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(225deg);
  transform: rotate(225deg);
}


/*#region MODULES */


/*#endregion */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 2px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: none;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: rgba(74, 168, 0, 0.6);
}

ul,
ol {
  padding-left: 40px;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  font: 400 100% 'Raleway', 'Lato';
  background-color: #282828;
  color: #CCC;
}

body {
  padding-bottom: 60px;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 310%;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 120%;
  color: #71AD37;
}

#slider1 {
  margin: 20px;
  font-family: 'Lato';
}

#slider1>ul>li:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: red;
}

#slider1>input:nth-of-type(3):checked~ul #bg {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 22px;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s 0.5s;
  -o-transition: 0.5s 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s 0.5s;
}

#slider1>input:nth-of-type(3):checked~ul #bg div {
  -moz-transform: translate(0);
  -ms-transform: translate(0);
  -o-transform: translate(0);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0);
  transform: translate(0);
  -moz-transition: 0.5s 0.9s;
  -o-transition: 0.5s 0.9s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s 0.9s;
  transition: 0.5s 0.9s;
}

#slider1>input:nth-of-type(6):checked~ul #dex-sign {
  -moz-animation: sign-anim 3.5s 0.5s steps(85) forwards;
  -o-animation: sign-anim 3.5s 0.5s steps(85) forwards;
  -webkit-animation: sign-anim 3.5s 0.5s steps(85) forwards;
  animation: sign-anim 3.5s 0.5s steps(85) forwards;
}

#bg {
  color: #000;
  padding: 22px 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 16%;
  height: 20%;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#bg:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -1px;
  top: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  background: green;
  -webkit-filter: blur(7px);
}

#bg:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 20;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  pointer-events: none;
}

#bg div {
  -moz-transform: translate(120%);
  -ms-transform: translate(120%);
  -o-transform: translate(120%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(120%);
  transform: translate(120%);
}

.scrollable p {
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: justify;
  line-height: 140%;
  font-size: 120%;
}

#center {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 25%;
}

#center a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-variant: small-caps;
}


/*___________________________________ LINK ___________________________________ */

a.nice-link {
  position: relative;
  color: #71ad37;
}

h1 a.nice-link:after {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #a5ff0e;
}

a.nice-link:after {
  text-align: justify;
  display: inline-block;
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #a5ff0e;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  background: #3A3A3A;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s;
  -o-transition: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

a.nice-link:hover {
  color: #71ad37;
}

a.nice-link:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}


/*___________________________________ SIGN ___________________________________ */

#dex-sign {
  width: 255px;
  height: 84px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 33%;
  top: 45%;
  opacity: 0.7;
  background: white 0 0 no-repeat;
}

#dex-sign:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-filter: invert(30%) brightness(80%) sepia(100%) contrast(110%) saturate(953%) hue-rotate(45deg);
}

@-webkit-keyframes sign-anim {
  to {
    background-position: 0 -7140px;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes sign-anim {
  to {
    background-position: 0 -7140px;
  }
}

@keyframes sign-anim {
  to {
    background-position: 0 -7140px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="csslider infinity" id="slider1">
  <input type="radio" name="slides" checked="checked" id="slides_1" />
  <input type="radio" name="slides" id="slides_2" />
  <input type="radio" name="slides" id="slides_3" />
  <input type="radio" name="slides" id="slides_4" />
  <input type="radio" name="slides" id="slides_5" />
  <input type="radio" name="slides" id="slides_6" />
  <ul>
    <li>Slide 1</li>
    <li>Slide 2</li>
    <li>Slide 3</li>
    <li>Slide 4</li>
    <li>Slide 5</li>
    <li>Slide 6</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="arrows">
    <label for="slides_1"></label>
    <label for="slides_2"></label>
    <label for="slides_3"></label>
    <label for="slides_4"></label>
    <label for="slides_5"></label>
    <label for="slides_6"></label>
    <label class="goto-first" for="slides_1"></label>
    <label class="goto-last" for="slides_6"></label>
  </div>
  <div class="navigation">
    <div>
      <label for="slides_1"></label>
      <label for="slides_2"></label>
      <label for="slides_3"></label>
      <label for="slides_4"></label>
      <label for="slides_5"></label>
      <label for="slides_6"></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[View on Codepen](https://codepen.io/codet/pen/bZqgGe).

---

### Edit

I came up with this solution:

```js
setInterval(function() {

  var currentID = document.querySelector('input[name="slides"]:checked').id;
  var idNoArr = currentID.split('');
  var intIdNo = parseInt(idNoArr[1]);
  var nextIdNo = intIdNo + 1;
  var NextId = idNoArr[0] + '' + nextIdNo;
  var NextInput = document.getElementById(NextId);

  if (!NextInput) {
    NextId = idNoArr[0] + '_1';
  }

  document.getElementById(NextId).checked = true;

}, 1000);
```

Comment: Did you ask the same question before?

Comment: In what way does it not work? What is the desired functionality and what specifically goes wrong?

Comment: Is working just fine... Specify the problem

Comment: Actually I want to set auto play function without jQuery. Its not work remove jQuery : https://codepen.io/codet/pen/drvvEV

Comment: did you check this ? https://codepen.io/doodlemarks/pen/xDvAw

Comment: Check https://codepen.io/doodlemarks/pen/xDvAw this pen.But I am not interested in Use jQuery library . Want to use only JavaScript.

Comment: Ok I got this solution :         setInterval(function(){
var currentID = document.querySelector('input[name="slides"]:checked').id;
var idNoArr = currentID.split('_');
var intIdNo = parseInt(idNoArr[1]);
var nextIdNo = intIdNo +1;
var NextId = idNoArr[0]+'_'+nextIdNo;
var NextInput = document.getElementById(NextId);
if(!NextInput){
NextId = idNoArr[0]+'_1';
}
document.getElementById(NextId).checked = true;
}, 1000);

Comment: That looks pretty gnarly. Personally, I'd opt for a cleaner more sustainable method than parsing IDs. But if it works for you, then it works! I appreciate your ingenuity.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues, including:

1. [`nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling) isn't limited to inputs, and may even select white space between elements.
2. Elements [don't have a `length` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Talk:DOM/element.length).
3. Setting an attribute only [sets the *default* state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27905978/setattributechecked-checked-only-works-one-time?lq=1), not the current state.

I recommend selecting a list of *all* the inputs with [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and then cycling through them using an index. To cycle the index within the appropriate bounds, I'm using the [`remainder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) of the current index divided by the total number of inputs.

**Edit:**

I see that your jQuery code determines which input is `checked` before changing the slide. This allows the automatic rotation to pick up where the user left off after they manually select a slide. I've modified my code accordingly.

You might also consider some functionality to stop or delay the automatic rotation if the user manually selects a slide. When someone clicks to a specific slide, I often choose to delay the automatic rotation for a few seconds or even have it stop completely. Just an idea.

---

Here's a working example:

```js
// select node list of all inputs
var allInputs = document.querySelectorAll('#slider1 input[type=radio]');

// function to determine index of "checked" input in the list
function getCheckedIndex(list) {
  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (list[i].checked) {
      return i;
    }
  }
}

// start the interval
setInterval(() => {

  // determine index of "checked" input
  let index = getCheckedIndex(allInputs);

  // determine the next index
  index = (index + 1) % allInputs.length;

  // set the "checked" property
  allInputs[index].checked = true;

}, 1000);
```

```css
.csslider {
  -moz-perspective: 1300px;
  -ms-perspective: 1300px;
  -webkit-perspective: 1300px;
  perspective: 1300px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 22px;
}

.csslider>input {
  display: none;
}

.csslider>input:nth-of-type(10):checked~ul li:first-of-type {
  margin-left: -900%;
}

.csslider>input:nth-of-type(9):checked~ul li:first-of-type {
  margin-left: -800%;
}

.csslider>input:nth-of-type(8):checked~ul li:first-of-type {
  margin-left: -700%;
}

.csslider>input:nth-of-type(7):checked~ul li:first-of-type {
  margin-left: -600%;
}

.csslider>input:nth-of-type(6):checked~ul li:first-of-type {
  margin-left: -500%;
}

.csslider>input:nth-of-type(5):checked~ul li:first-of-type {
  margin-left: -400%;
}

.csslider>input:nth-of-type(4):checked~ul li:first-of-type {
  margin-left: -300%;
}

.csslider>input:nth-of-type(3):checked~ul li:first-of-type {
  margin-left: -200%;
}

.csslider>input:nth-of-type(2):checked~ul li:first-of-type {
  margin-left: -100%;
}

.csslider>input:nth-of-type(1):checked~ul li:first-of-type {
  margin-left: 0%;
}

.csslider>ul {
  position: relative;
  width: 820px;
  height: 420px;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  background-color: #3A3A3A;
  border: 10px solid #3A3A3A;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.csslider>ul>li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-size: initial;
  line-height: normal;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 1.3, 0.65, 1);
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 1.3, 0.65, 1);
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 1.3, 0.65, 1);
  vertical-align: top;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  white-space: normal;
}

.csslider>ul>li.scrollable {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.csslider>.navigation {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -8px;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.csslider>.navigation>div {
  margin-left: -100%;
}

.csslider>.navigation label {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 4px;
  padding: 4px;
  background: #3A3A3A;
}

.csslider>.navigation label:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.csslider>.navigation label:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -6px;
  margin-top: -6px;
  background: #71ad37;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 6px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.csslider>.arrows {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.csslider.inside .navigation {
  bottom: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.csslider.inside .navigation label {
  border: 1px solid #7e7e7e;
}

.csslider>input:nth-of-type(1):checked~.navigation label:nth-of-type(1):after,
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(2):checked~.navigation label:nth-of-type(2):after,
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(3):checked~.navigation label:nth-of-type(3):after,
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(4):checked~.navigation label:nth-of-type(4):after,
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(5):checked~.navigation label:nth-of-type(5):after,
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(6):checked~.navigation label:nth-of-type(6):after,
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(7):checked~.navigation label:nth-of-type(7):after,
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(8):checked~.navigation label:nth-of-type(8):after,
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(9):checked~.navigation label:nth-of-type(9):after,
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(10):checked~.navigation label:nth-of-type(10):after,
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(11):checked~.navigation label:nth-of-type(11):after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.csslider>.arrows {
  position: absolute;
  left: -31px;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 26px;
  padding: 0 31px;
  z-index: 0;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.csslider>.arrows label {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: -50%;
  padding: 13px;
  box-shadow: inset 2px -2px 0 1px #3A3A3A;
  cursor: pointer;
  -moz-transition: box-shadow 0.15s, margin 0.15s;
  -o-transition: box-shadow 0.15s, margin 0.15s;
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow 0.15s, margin 0.15s;
  transition: box-shadow 0.15s, margin 0.15s;
}

.csslider>.arrows label:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 3px -3px 0 2px #71ad37;
  margin: 0 0px;
}

.csslider>.arrows label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -100%;
  left: -100%;
  height: 300%;
  width: 300%;
}

.csslider.infinity>input:first-of-type:checked~.arrows label.goto-last,
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(1):checked~.arrows>label:nth-of-type(0),
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(2):checked~.arrows>label:nth-of-type(1),
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(3):checked~.arrows>label:nth-of-type(2),
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(4):checked~.arrows>label:nth-of-type(3),
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(5):checked~.arrows>label:nth-of-type(4),
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(6):checked~.arrows>label:nth-of-type(5),
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(7):checked~.arrows>label:nth-of-type(6),
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(8):checked~.arrows>label:nth-of-type(7),
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(9):checked~.arrows>label:nth-of-type(8),
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(10):checked~.arrows>label:nth-of-type(9),
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(11):checked~.arrows>label:nth-of-type(10) {
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  right: auto;
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.csslider.infinity>input:last-of-type:checked~.arrows label.goto-first,
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(1):checked~.arrows>label:nth-of-type(2),
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(2):checked~.arrows>label:nth-of-type(3),
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(3):checked~.arrows>label:nth-of-type(4),
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(4):checked~.arrows>label:nth-of-type(5),
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(5):checked~.arrows>label:nth-of-type(6),
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(6):checked~.arrows>label:nth-of-type(7),
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(7):checked~.arrows>label:nth-of-type(8),
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(8):checked~.arrows>label:nth-of-type(9),
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(9):checked~.arrows>label:nth-of-type(10),
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(10):checked~.arrows>label:nth-of-type(11),
.csslider>input:nth-of-type(11):checked~.arrows>label:nth-of-type(12) {
  display: block;
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
  -moz-transform: rotate(225deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(225deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(225deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(225deg);
  transform: rotate(225deg);
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 2px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: none;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: rgba(74, 168, 0, 0.6);
}

ul,
ol {
  padding-left: 40px;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  font: 400 100% 'Raleway', 'Lato';
  background-color: #282828;
  color: #CCC;
}

body {
  padding-bottom: 60px;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 310%;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 120%;
  color: #71AD37;
}

#slider1 {
  margin: 20px;
  font-family: 'Lato';
}

#slider1>ul>li:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: red;
}

#slider1>input:nth-of-type(3):checked~ul #bg {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 22px;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s 0.5s;
  -o-transition: 0.5s 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s 0.5s;
}

#slider1>input:nth-of-type(3):checked~ul #bg div {
  -moz-transform: translate(0);
  -ms-transform: translate(0);
  -o-transform: translate(0);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0);
  transform: translate(0);
  -moz-transition: 0.5s 0.9s;
  -o-transition: 0.5s 0.9s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s 0.9s;
  transition: 0.5s 0.9s;
}

#slider1>input:nth-of-type(6):checked~ul #dex-sign {
  -moz-animation: sign-anim 3.5s 0.5s steps(85) forwards;
  -o-animation: sign-anim 3.5s 0.5s steps(85) forwards;
  -webkit-animation: sign-anim 3.5s 0.5s steps(85) forwards;
  animation: sign-anim 3.5s 0.5s steps(85) forwards;
}

#bg {
  color: #000;
  padding: 22px 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 16%;
  height: 20%;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#bg:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -1px;
  top: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  background: green;
  -webkit-filter: blur(7px);
}

#bg:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 20;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  pointer-events: none;
}

#bg div {
  -moz-transform: translate(120%);
  -ms-transform: translate(120%);
  -o-transform: translate(120%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(120%);
  transform: translate(120%);
}

.scrollable p {
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: justify;
  line-height: 140%;
  font-size: 120%;
}

#center {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 25%;
}

#center a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-variant: small-caps;
}


/*___________________________________ LINK ___________________________________ */

a.nice-link {
  position: relative;
  color: #71ad37;
}

h1 a.nice-link:after {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #a5ff0e;
}

a.nice-link:after {
  text-align: justify;
  display: inline-block;
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #a5ff0e;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  background: #3A3A3A;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s;
  -o-transition: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

a.nice-link:hover {
  color: #71ad37;
}

a.nice-link:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}


/*___________________________________ SIGN ___________________________________ */

#dex-sign {
  width: 255px;
  height: 84px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 33%;
  top: 45%;
  opacity: 0.7;
  background: white 0 0 no-repeat;
}

#dex-sign:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-filter: invert(30%) brightness(80%) sepia(100%) contrast(110%) saturate(953%) hue-rotate(45deg);
}

@-webkit-keyframes sign-anim {
  to {
    background-position: 0 -7140px;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes sign-anim {
  to {
    background-position: 0 -7140px;
  }
}

@keyframes sign-anim {
  to {
    background-position: 0 -7140px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="csslider infinity" id="slider1">
  <input type="radio" name="slides" id="slides_1">
  <input type="radio" name="slides" id="slides_2">
  <input type="radio" name="slides" id="slides_3" checked>
  <input type="radio" name="slides" id="slides_4">
  <input type="radio" name="slides" id="slides_5">
  <input type="radio" name="slides" id="slides_6">
  <ul>
    <li>Slide 1</li>
    <li>Slide 2</li>
    <li>Slide 3</li>
    <li>Slide 4</li>
    <li>Slide 5</li>
    <li>Slide 6</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="arrows">
    <label for="slides_1"></label>
    <label for="slides_2"></label>
    <label for="slides_3"></label>
    <label for="slides_4"></label>
    <label for="slides_5"></label>
    <label for="slides_6"></label>
    <label class="goto-first" for="slides_1"></label>
    <label class="goto-last" for="slides_6"></label>
  </div>
  <div class="navigation">
    <div>
      <label for="slides_1"></label>
      <label for="slides_2"></label>
      <label for="slides_3"></label>
      <label for="slides_4"></label>
      <label for="slides_5"></label>
      <label for="slides_6"></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```