# How to save function information in an Array()

Tags: javascript, html, class, attributes, tags

Is there any way to access the attributes of all html elements in a certain `class` or `tagName` and set an attribute. For example, to access all the attributes of class `navT` and set attribute `align` to center? Or to access the attributes of all `table` tags and set attribute `align` to `center` (Possibly without jQuery)? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('.navT').forEach(element => { element.align = "center"; });` - for `<table>` use `querySelectorAll('table')` or `getElementsByTagName('table')`

Comment: @JonathanLonowski `forEach` is a fairly recent addition to `NodeList` - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach - I still suggest OP to use your proposed array conversion for compatibility with older browsers if desired

Comment: Related: [javascript setattribute to multiple element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18455353/javascript-setattribute-to-multiple-element) (has answers for both with and without jQuery)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're trying to accomplish (as with anything) but probably the most "down and dirty" and simplest way would be to use:

```
var arr = document.getElementsByClassName("navT");
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  arr[i].style.textAlign = "center";
}
```

Depending on what I were doing I would probably prefer to just make a class in my CSS
    .center {text-align: center;}
and add the class to each element. Just put the following in the for loop above:
    arr[i].classList.add("center");

Hope that helps!