# How to get multiple elements of a form and add an attribute to them?

Tags: javascript, forms, dom, input

```html
<form name="myform">
      <fieldset>
          <legend>Delivery Information</legend>
          
          <p>Country: <input pattern="^[A-Za-z]" type="text" name="textInput" size="25" placeholder="input country..."></p>
          <p>Street: <input pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9]" type="text" name="street" size="30" placeholder="input street..."></p>
          <p>City: <input pattern="^[A-Za-z ]" type="text" name="textInput" size="20" placeholder="input city..."></p>
          <p>Zip: <input pattern="(\d{5}([\-]\d{4})?)" type="text" name="zip" size="5" placeholder="#####"></p>
      </fieldset>
</form>
```

So, I have a form and I want to get all input elements by name "textInput" (I have other inputs) using JavaScript DOM, and add an attribute `oninvalid="please, only use letters"`.

Only JavaScript, so no jQuery.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript setattribute to multiple element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18455353/javascript-setattribute-to-multiple-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function:

```
function changeAttributes() {
    var x = document.getElementsByName("textInput");
    for(var i = 0; i < x.length, i++) {
        x[i].setAttribute("oninvalid", "please, only use letters");
    }
}
```

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
 $('input[name=textInput]').attr("oninvalid", "please, only use letters");
```