# How to disable focus on specific html elements?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, focus

I have custom input component in `vue js`, and in this component i have input and two buttons.when input loose focus, i want to focus on next input, but now it focus on those buttons.
finally i should press tab key three times to focus on next input.

> Is there any html attribute for disabling focus on some elements? or there is a javascript way?

Comment: `pointer-events: none;` disables click

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which HTML elements can receive focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599660/which-html-elements-can-receive-focus)

Comment: Add tabIndex either static or programmatically https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772438/can-i-dynamically-set-tabindex-in-javascript

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The tabindex attribute controls tabbing. Set it to -1 and the tab key will not stop on that element.

```
<button tabindex="-1">click me</button>
```

Comment: can you provide a link to where I can find this in vuejs docs?

Comment: it is not related to vue specifically but a general web standard

Answer (score 1):

You could use the blur event which is an equivalent of https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onfocusout.asp 
`<input v-on:blur="handleBlur">`

To trigger something when you lose focus.

You also could create a tabindex `tabindex="0"` on elements to determine the order of tabbing.

Unfortunately you can't make an element non focus-able unless you want to disable the whole element. Because then you couldn't type anything into that input.