# How to add tab index dynamic

Tags: html, css, tabindex

I need to place dynamic boxes on the right side of the screen and position starting from right to left.

Example 5 boxes : box1,box2,box3,box4,box5 and displayed like This
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFQj3.png)

If there is no space to accommodate all boxes in one line, image look like this.
 [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOGnJ.png)

Is there any way can add tabindex starting with top to bottom and let to right?

I already tried the tabindexing decending order of boxed and its working in first scenario, but in second the order going like this: Box5,Box4,Box3,Box2,Box1.

**I am looking for this order Box3,Box2,Box1,Box5,Box4**

Example image1: tabindex starting from Box5,Box4,Box3,Box2,Box1

Example 2: Box3,Box2,Box1,Box5,Box4

Appreciate any help.

Comment: You could name boxes in the order of tabindex you need then pass their name/id onto a function to assign it https://stackoverflow.com/a/3772464/10634638 or alternatively don’t change tabindex let run default order, but change order of the boxes as needed.

Comment: Hi @bestinamir, Thanks for your comment.